# In Keras, how to apply softmax function on each row of the weight matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, softmax

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Input
from keras.layers import Dense

a = Input(shape=(3,))
b = Dense(2, use_bias=False)(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
```

Suppose that the weights of the `Dense` layer in the above code is `[[2, 3], [3, 1], [-1, 1]]`. If we give `[[2, 1, 3]]` as an input to the `model`, then the output will be:

[image: no softmax]

But I want to apply the softmax function to each row of the `Dense` layer, so that the output will be:

[image: with softmax]

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean you want the softmax to be applied on the weights of Dense layer and not on its output, right?

Comment: @today Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to define a custom layer by subclassing the `Dense` layer and overriding its `call` method:

```
from keras import backend as K

class CustomDense(Dense):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDense, self).__init__(units, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        output = K.dot(inputs, K.softmax(self.kernel, axis=-1))
        if self.use_bias:
            output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')
        if self.activation is not None:
            output = self.activation(output)
        return output
```

Test to make sure it works:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(CustomDense(2, use_bias=False, input_shape=(3,)))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

import numpy as np

w = np.array([[2,3], [3,1], [1,-1]])
inp = np.array([[2,1,3]])

model.layers[0].set_weights([w])
print(model.predict(inp))

# output
[[4.0610714 1.9389288]]
```

Verify it using numpy:

```
soft_w = np.exp(w) / np.sum(np.exp(w), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
print(np.dot(inp, soft_w))

[[4.06107115 1.93892885]]
```